# Terraform error: Error: creating Subnet: Original Error: Code="NetcfgInvalidSubnet" Message="Subnet 'internal' is not valid in virtual network

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create resources in azure using terraform, a SQL server database and also a virtual machine.I get the error.

`│ Error: creating Subnet: (Name "db_subnetn" / Virtual Network Name "tf_dev-network" / Resource Group "terraform_youtube"): network.SubnetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="NetcfgInvalidSubnet" Message="Subnet 'db_subnetn' is not valid in virtual network 'tf_dev-network'." Details=[]`

What have I done ?

followed the link here [Error while provisioning Terraform subnet using azurerm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904353/error-while-provisioning-terraform-subnet-using-azurerm)

I deleted other network resources using thesame IP range.

My network understanding is pretty basic, however from my research it appears that 10.0.0.0/16 is quite a large IP range and can lead to overlaps. So what did I do, I changed the virtual network IP range from 10.0.0.0/16 to 10.0.1.0/24 to restrict the range, what simply happened is that the error changed to

`│ Error: creating Subnet: (Name "internal" / Virtual Network Name "tf_dev-network" / Resource Group "terraform_youtube"): network.SubnetsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="NetcfgInvalidSubnet" Message="Subnet 'internal' is not valid in virtual network 'tf_dev-network'." Details=[]`

At this stage, I would be grateful if someone can explain what is going wrong here and what needs to be done. Thanks in advance

My files are as follows.

dbcode.tf

```
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sqlserver" {
  name                         = "tom556sqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "khdfd9898rerer"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-jlhdfdf89-p455w0rd"

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_sql_virtual_network_rule" "sqlvnetrule" {
    name = "sql_vnet_rule"
    resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
    server_name = azurerm_sql_server.sqlserver.name
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.db_subnet.id
  
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "db_subnet" {
    name = "db_subnetn"
    resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
    virtual_network_name    = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
    address_prefixes        = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
    service_endpoints       = ["Microsoft.Sql"]
  
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_gp" {
  name="terraform_youtube"
  location = "UK South"

  tags = {
    "owner" = "Rahman"
    "purpose" = "Practice terraform"
  }
}


variable "prefix" {
  default = "tf_dev"
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_B1ls"

  # Uncomment this line to delete the OS disk automatically when deleting the VM
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  # Uncomment this line to delete the data disks automatically when deleting the VM
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which error  is generated by the code that you presented in the question, ? You have to different errors reported after some changes, yet its not clear if the code shown is before change, after change, or something else?

Comment: Please use subnet prefix for db_subnet ["10.0.3.0/24"] instead of ["10.0.2.0/24"] then try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested with your code in my environment was getting the same error.**

[image]

To fix the issue you need to change `address_prefixes` for `db_subnet` to `["10.0.3.0/24"]` as `["10.0.2.0/24"]` address range is already using by `internal` subnet in your `main.tf` and also check update for `sqlvnetrule` and do the changes in your `dbcode.tf` file.

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver" {
  name                         = "tom556sqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "khdfd9898rerer"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-jlhdfdf89-p455w0rd"

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "db_subnet" {
    name = "db_subnetn"
    resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
    virtual_network_name    = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
    address_prefixes        = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
    service_endpoints       = ["Microsoft.Sql"]
  
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_network_rule" "sqlvnetrule" {
    name = "sql_vnet_rule"
    #resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.resource_gp.name
    #server_name = azurerm_sql_server.sqlserver.name
    server_id = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.id
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.db_subnet.id
  
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, this worked. I would be really grateful if you can explain a little more whilst I also read up. Also in your answer, do you mean that `10.0.2.0/24` is already used in main.tf for the VM not on dbcode.tf ?. After creating the resources, I can see that the VM has an ip of `10.0.2.4` whilst the DB is on a subnet of `10.0.3/24`.Is there a guide that explains this in lay mans terms please, my background is not networking. If I understood the configuration, this should have been an obvious issue and one that ought to be able to fix on my own. Thanks once more. @RahulKumarShaw-MT

Comment: You were creating different same ie **internal** and **db_subnet** with same address prefix thats won't possible. You should create subnet that not collaps with range of another subnet in your resource group/subscription.

Comment: Sorry i miss write few words in my answer now please check hope all your network related doubt should cleared. Let me know if still finding any diffculties to understand.